# What is the main thread in GCD?

Tags: multithreading, grand-central-dispatch

What exactly is the main thread in Grand Central Dispatch? Is it a thread created when the program starts up (maybe just before the `main()` function gets called), which is arbitrarily called "the main thread"? Or is it the program's main execution flow, which is always created for every running process? I think the first option is the right one, because it's not possible to send blocks to be executed by the program's main execution flow, I guess, unless this is done explicitly. So, the main thread in GCD must be another thread that is created to wait for blocks to be executed. Is it right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GCD has no main thread unless running in the context of a CF/Foundation based process that has one of its own. If you use dispatch_main there's no main thread.

Comment: so you mean that CoreFoundation is who creates the so-called main thread and this thread waits for events, such as a block dispatching event? If yes, is this thread a CFRunLoop which is always created implicitly for all programs that are linked against CoreFoundation?

Comment: Threads are not runloops. Threads have runloops. However, the main queue is indeed integrated with and driven by the main runloop. In a pure-libdispatch program, you wouldn't use the main queue.

Comment: Sorry for what I said about threads and runloops; I expressed myself poorly. But, any way, thank you very much!

Comment: And, by the way, do you have any link to some documentation related to the connection between libdispatch and CoreFoundation?

Comment: Hm. I'm not sure if its documented, but you can see how it's structured if you set a breakpoint in a block dispatched on the main queue, then look at the function names in the stack trace.

Answer (score 1):

Every UI application on OS X has a main thread - it's where UI updates are (and must be) performed.  GCD associates a queue with this thread, the main queue, and is also free to execute blocks from other queues on this thread though, in practice, it generally creates other threads for this purpose as it is generally considered inadvisable to block the main thread for any length of time (doing so brings up the dreaded SPOD, or spinning pizza of death, cursor).

Calling dispatch_main() also does not destroy or obviate the need for a main thread, it simply blocks it (which is why UI apps should use the run loop instead).

Comment: Thanks, jkh. And how is it possible to make the main thread stop its main flow and execute a block? Is it by sending a signal to the main thread (after setting the correct action for that signal with `sigaction` or something when the program is starting up)?

Comment: There are no signals involved - GCD simply knows which blocks are enqueued on all queues it is managing and, assuming the run loop behavior allows it, executes each block on the most appropriate thread. This is why the main thread is generally associated most directly with the main queue; then it is at least clear to the programmer that blocking the main thread for too long will bring on a SPOD.